# manipular boton toggle con php

Tags: php, mysql

soy un programador principiante, tengo una tabla que contiene datos de usuario como nombre, apellido direccion y un boton toggle correspondiente al campo status en mi tabla MySQL. Este lo quiero usar para enviar un varchar "pagó" o "no pagó" deacuerdo al ID del usuario al que quiera modificar su status.
  mi problema es que no se como manipular este boton para que cuando este en "no pago" envie a mysql "no pago" y cuando este en pagó envie "pagó" al campo status de mi DB.
A la vez tengo dos tablas aparte, una que esta esperando los usuarios que contenga en status "No pago" y la otra que espera los que contienen "Pagó" para separar los usuarios segun su status.

adjunto una imagen y mi codigo hasta el momento.

esta es mi tabla html

```
 <?php 

      foreach($usuarios as $usuario){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $usuario['id_us']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $usuario['name_us']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $usuario['apellido_us']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $usuario['DNI']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $usuario['dir_us']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $usuario['tel_us']?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No pagado" data-off="Pagado" data-onstyle="danger" data-offstyle="success" id="pago">
      </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#editar_<?php echo $usuario['id_us']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
            <a href="#borrar_<?php echo $usuario['id_us']; ?>"class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        </td>
        <?php include('modaleditar.php') ?>
        </tr>
        <!-- MODAL EDITAR -->

      <?php 
        }; 
      ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Acá en la imagen muestro los dos estados del toggle pero sin funcionar.]

espero me puedan ayudar, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Me parce que con un Formulario y un boton submit() <form></form> todos los campos input dentro del formulario se postean; a través de la herramienta Desarrollador WEB de firefox o Chrome puedes ver que valor esta posteando la página y bajo que nombre de variable, independiente de esto también podrías capturar el comportamiento del botón a través del evento onchange() y usar ajax para cambiar el dato en la base.

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probar lo que me dices.